# How can I unit test with Proto DataStore?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, datastore, mockk

I am trying to test DataSource with Proto DataStore.

```
class PreferenceDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val userPreferences: DataStore<UserPreferences>
)
```

So, I am implementing like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class PreferenceDataSourceTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var prefDataSource: PreferenceDataSource

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
        val datastore = DataStore<UserPreferences>() // this doesn't work.
        prefDataSource = PreferenceDataSource(userPreferences = datastore)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {

    }
}
```

How can I test with Proto DataStore? I mean, I don't want to fake it but want to see if it really updates or deletes correctly as well.

Comment: Well, this is instrumentedTest. And I use proto datastore.

Comment: @F.G. well, It's instrumentedTest and I don't like it. That's why I use Robolectric.

Comment: Yeah, sry, then I can't help you

Comment: Any luck with this? I am also trying to test proto datastore

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with Robolectric.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class PreferenceDataSourceTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    private lateinit var dataSource: PreferenceDataSource
    private lateinit var dataStore: DataStore<UserPreferences>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
        dataStore = DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer(),
            scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined + SupervisorJob()),
        ) {
            context.dataStoreFile("test_user_preferences.pb")
        }
        dataSource = PreferenceDataSource(userPreferences = dataStore)
    }
}
```